# how to display multiple views on different pages in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I am new on codeigniter. I want to display multipe view on different pages. I create a page on which I create an edit button. I want that when I click on edit button I rediect on another page. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
class Edit extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
    }
    function edit()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        if($this->input->post('edit') == True)
        {
            redirect('edit');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $this->load->view('edit_view');

Comment: can you please elaborate @AlphaMale

Comment: please read the documentation here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: @jayant.porwal it depends. are you asking how to load a view???

Comment: @AlphaMale i am asking how to load view on another page . . . when i click on edit i want to switch on another page

Comment: @jayant.porwal Am glad it helped. an upvote will help me too :P

Comment: @AlphaMale hey when i implement the solution you gave , my logout funtion was disabled . ..what can i do

Comment: giving a method the same name of controller is a bad practice, it would confuse normal people (I am not sure of PHP) but a method with the same name of controller is the old php-way of "__construct"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View 1: (Where your link is present)

```
<?php echo anchor('Edit/edit', 'Edit Value'); // Here Edit is your controller and edit is the function name. ?>
```

And in Edit controller modify it like this:

```
class Edit extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
    }

    function edit()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        if($this->input->post('edit') == True)
        {
            //redirect('edit'); //Do not use this as this line will call the same function again.
            $this->load->view('edit_view'); // where edit_view.php is present in your views directory. 
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The button will be on view which means on click of a button on view it should redirect to some other page(view ):

use anchor this on view:

```
 <?php echo anchor('controller_name/function_name', 'acnchor_name'); ?>

 <?php echo anchor('Edit/edit', 'edit'); ?>
```

where edit must be a name of function and view .

Now there will be a link on view on click of it it will redirected to edit view.

hope will help you!